# Is There a Variant of regex_replace that Supports Inline Code?

Tags: c++, regex, perl, replace, substitution

Perl has the `e` regex modifier which allows Perl code rather than just a string to formulate the replacement: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace Though that example is not the greatest as there are switches to accomplish this. For those of you who understand Perl here's an example that makes more sense:

```
$string = "StackOverflow user: Jonathan Mee";

$string =~ s/:\s*(.*)$/$1 == "Jonathan Mee" ? ": ".$1." is AWESOME!" : ": ".$1." is ???"/e;

print $string; #Will print "StackOverflow user: Jonathan Mee is AWESOME!"
```

Is there a `regex_replace` variant in C++ that will allow me to do something similar? As in code inline for the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`regex_replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) has 6 different overloads. The `fmt` argument is used the same way for each of them:

> A string with the replacement for each match.
>   This may include format specifiers and escape sequences that are replaced by the characters they represent.

Each of the 6 overloads also sport a `flags` argument which is used to control, "how `fmt` is formatted." The `fmt` related options are:

- `format_default`: Default formatting
  Uses the standard formatting rules to replace matches (those used by ECMAScript's replace method).
- `format_sed` sed formatting
  Uses the same rules as the sed utility in POSIX to replace matches.
- `format_no_copy` No copy
  The sections in the target sequence that do not match the regular expression are not copied when replacing matches.
- `format_first_only` First only
  Only the first occurrence of a regular expression is replaced.

Note that none of the `fmt` overloads, nor the `flags` support in-line code. So the answer is: **No, there is no variant of `regex_replace` that supports in-line code.**

---

However if you were willing to use a STD algorithm in conjunction with [`regex_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_iterator/), you could use a lambda to accomplish in-line code.

```
const string foo("StackOverflow user: Jonathan Mee");
vector<string> bar;

transform(regex_iterator<string::const_iterator>(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), regex(".*:\\s*(.*)")),
          regex_iterator<string::const_iterator>(),
          back_inserter(bar),
          [](const smatch& i){auto result = i.str();

                              if (!result.empty()){
                                  result += (i.str(1) == "Jonathan Mee" ? " is AWESOME!" : " is ???");
                              }
                              return result;});
```

As you can see a lambda is usable in the `transform` taking in the current `regex_iterator`'s `smatch`. This is very extensible to multi-line strings, in the example of `string foo("StackOverflow user: Jonathan Mee\nStackOverflow user: user0");` the output would be:

> StackOverflow user: Jonathan Mee is AWESOME!
>   StackOverflow user: user0 is ???

Clearly there are some trade-offs working with just an `smatch` versus `regex_replace`. Where `str(1)` falls within `str()` is not specified. Here I take advantage of the fact that it is right at the end of `foo` rather than somewhere that has to be found in the middle of `foo`. But it should be mentioned that the same difficulty befalls Perl's `e`-modifier, so I think this is pretty much on par.