# Oracle: Is There a Variant of REGEX_REPLACE that supports inline code?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

**Note**: This question has originally been asked in the context of c++ `regexp_replace` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29367546)). However, it occurred to me that it might be of interest in the oracle universe, too. The wording of the question has been adopted with the kind permission of the original author.

Perl has the `e` regex modifier which allows Perl code rather than just a string to formulate the replacement: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace Though that example is not the greatest as there are switches to accomplish this. For those of you who understand Perl here's an example that makes more sense:

```
$string = "StackOverflow user: Old Faithful";

$string =~ s/:\s*(.*)$/$1 == "Old Faithful" ? ": ".$1." is AWESOME!" : ": ".$1." is ???"/e;

print $string; #Will print "StackOverflow user: Old Faithful is AWESOME!"
```

Is there a `regex_replace` variant in (Pl)Sql that will allow me to do something similar? As in code inline for the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `REGEX_REPLACE` doesn't cater for dynamically generated replacement strings.

However, you can come close. This answer contains 3 variations of the same idea. In a nutshell:

- Variation 1: static
  simplest, computations in expression syntax only, sql compatible, performance nightmare
- Variation 2: static + function call

  simple, complex computations, sql compatible, performance nightmare;
  privileges to create function/packages needed.
- Variation 3: dynamic
  complex, utmost flexibility in executed code, not sql compatible, performance ... you guessed it.

The basic idea of all methods is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get hold of the capture group contents and feed these contents to the code computing the data actually substituted with it.
In Variation 1 this code would be the expression itself, variation 2 hides this code in a function body and variation 3 implements it as a dynamic plsql block around it.

***Variant 1 (static)***

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get hold of the capture group contents and feed the expression to process this data accordingly:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    text_orig_yep VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Old Faithful';
    text_orig_nay VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Some Nobody';
    text_pattern  VARCHAR2(1000) := ':\s*(.*)$';
    text_repl     VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    text_repl :=
       REGEXP_REPLACE (
            text_orig_yep
          , text_pattern
          , CASE REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)
               WHEN 'Old Faithful' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)||' is AWESOME!'
               ELSE                     REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)||' is ???' 
            END
       );
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
    text_repl :=
       REGEXP_REPLACE (
            text_orig_nay
          , text_pattern
          , CASE REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_nay, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)
               WHEN 'Old Faithful' THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)||' is AWESOME!'
               ELSE                     REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)||' is ???' 
            END
       );
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
END;
/
show error
```

***Variant 2 (static + function call)***

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get hold of the capture group contents and feed a function to compute results. This way you can perform complex computations that are impossible or cumbersome to express as a plsql expression.

```
set serveroutput on
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_rreval ( match_1 IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE match_1
            WHEN 'Old Faithful' THEN match_1||' is AWESOME!'
            ELSE                     match_1||' is ???' 
        END
    ;
END test_rreval;   
/
show error

DECLARE
    text_orig_yep VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Old Faithful';
    text_orig_nay VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Some Nobody';
    text_pattern  VARCHAR2(1000) := ':\s*(.*)$';
    text_repl     VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    text_repl :=
       REGEXP_REPLACE (
            text_orig_yep
          , text_pattern
          , test_rreval ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1) )
       );
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
    text_repl :=
       REGEXP_REPLACE (
            text_orig_nay
          , text_pattern
          , test_rreval ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_nay, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1) )
       );
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
END;
/
show error
```

***Variant 3 (dynamic)***

You gain utmost flexibility at the cost of performance and maintainability by generating a dynamic plsql block to produce your result.As a perk you can keep closer to the perl syntax ( but you can tweak variation 2 accordingly ).

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    text_orig_yep VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Old Faithful';
    text_orig_nay VARCHAR2(1000) := 'StackOverflow user: Some Nobody';
    text_pattern  VARCHAR2(1000) := ':\s*(.*)$';
    text_repl     VARCHAR2(1000);
    dyncode       VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
    dyncode := 'DECLARE "$1" VARCHAR2(32000) := :1; BEGIN :outvar := REGEXP_REPLACE ( :text_orig, :text_pattern, CASE "$1" WHEN ''Old Faithful'' THEN "$1"||'' is AWESOME!'' ELSE "$1"||'' is ???'' END ); END;';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dyncode 
                USING IN   REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_yep, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)
                    , OUT  text_repl
                    , IN   text_orig_yep
                    , IN   text_pattern
                    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dyncode 
                USING IN   REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_orig_nay, text_pattern, 1, 1, '', 1)
                    , OUT  text_repl
                    , IN   text_orig_nay
                    , IN   text_pattern
                    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ( text_repl );
END;
/
show error
```